# Automorphisms of algebras and orthogonal groups

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, orthogonal-groups

This is a followup of [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334743/linear-maps-preserved-by-algebra-automorphisms/).

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional associative unital $F$-algebra. According to YCor's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/334759/2383) in the previous link, the property that a given linear map $s_A : A\to F$ is preserved by the automorphisms of $A$ is not preserved by scalar extensions.

Notice nevertheless that in YCor's [example](https://mathoverflow.net/a/334759/2383), the bilinear map $(x,y)\in A\times A\mapsto s_A(xy)\in F$ is degenerate, so we might wonder what happens if this bilinear map is non-degenerate. This yields two questions.

**Question 1.** Let $s_A:A\to F$ be a linear map such that  $(x,y)\in A\times A\mapsto s_A(xy)\in F$ is non-degenerate. If $s_A\circ \varphi=s_A$ for all $\varphi\in \operatorname{Aut}_{\text{$F$-alg}}(A)$, does $s_{A\otimes_F K}$ have the same property for all field extensions $K/F$ (where $s_{A\otimes_F K}(a\otimes 1)=s_A(a)$ and is extended by $K$-linearity)?

Here is a stronger version of Question 1.

**Question 2.** Let $b: V\times V \to F$ be a non-degenerate bilinear form (not necessarily symmetric). If every automorphism of $A$ is also an automorphism of the bilinear form $b$, is the same true for $b_K$ and all $K/F$, where  $b_{K}$ is defined as you would think?

The last question is about existence.

**Question 3.** Given $A$, does there exists a non-degenerate bilinear form $(V,b)$ such that we have an injective morphism of affine group schemes $\rho: \operatorname{Aut}_{\text{alg}}(A)\to \operatorname{Aut}_{\text{bil}}(V,b)=O(V,b)$?

I'm not asking $b$ to be symmetric nor the base field $F$ to have characteristic different from $2$, so both group schemes might be not smooth. I'd be happy to make extra assumptions on $F$ if it is really necessary.

Concerning Question 3, I suspect that the answer is YES iff $\operatorname{Aut}(A)$ is finite, even if I don't see right now how to write a detailed proof.

I think that an example of $b$ to Question 3 would easily imply that Question 2 has a positive answer for this $b$.

Comment: As in my previous answer I'd suggest to write $s_F$ rather than $s_A$, so that we can write $s_K$ for $s_A\otimes_FK$.